# Best way to print data from two columns of mySQL database to jTextfield one after another

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans, resultset

I am trying to make a program in which i read an input from the user i.e. in the textfield named  `gname` and store its value to a string called `grammar`. Now this input is what sorts my output from the database.

Database looks like this 
[image]

So when user enters `G1` in the textfield it should display records in such a way

```
A->ab,A-ab,B->b
```

But it only shows 1st element when i use `if(myRs.next)` and last one if i use `while(myRs.next()`.

current output is 
[image]

Here is the code for this:

its all in try catch block

```
String grammar = gname.getText();

        myCon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/grammar", "root", "");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Connected to database");
        mystmt = myCon.createStatement(
                ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String query = "SELECT starting_symbol, value from starting_symbol where grammar= '" + grammar + "'";
        String query2 = "SELECT non_terminals, terminals from input_values where grammar= '" + grammar + "'";
        mystmt.addBatch(query);
        mystmt.addBatch(query2);
        myCon.setAutoCommit(false);

        mystmt.addBatch(query);
        mystmt.addBatch(query2);
        myRs = mystmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (myRs.next()) {

            String s = myRs.getString("starting_symbol");
            String val = myRs.getString("value");

            output.setText(s + "-> " + val);

        }
        myRs = mystmt.executeQuery(query2);

        ArrayList<String> list_one = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> list_two = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (myRs.next()) {
            list_one.add(myRs.getString("non_terminals"));
            list_two.add(myRs.getString("terminals"));
            for (int i = 0; i < list_one.size(); i++) {
                output_2.setText(list_one.get(i) + "->" + list_two.get(i));

            }

        }
```

Please help me in getting the correct outut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `StringBuilder` Luke

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
while (myRs.next()) {

    String s = myRs.getString("starting_symbol");
    String val = myRs.getString("value");
    if (b.length() > 0) {
        b.append(',');
    }
    b.append(s + "-> " + val);

}
output.setText(b.toString());
```

And do the same for output_2 field

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet can be just like the following:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (myRs.next()) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) sb.append(",");
        sb.append(myRs.getString("non_terminals"))
          .append("->")
          .append(myRs.getString("terminals"));
    }
```

Instead of calling output_2.setText multiple times that only set the text to be the last fetch value of `non_terminals -> terminals` in this case B->b.